# UIViewController dealloc after init

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, init, dealloc

Why myView is dealloc after init?

**MainViewController:**

```
[MOBubbleView hudWithBody:@"123123" bubblePoint:CGPointMake(220, headerMenu.center.y) hidesAfter:2 show:YES];
```

**MOBubbleView.h:**

```
@interface MOBubbleView : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) float hudHideDelay;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *itemColor;

+ (MOBubbleView*)hudWithBody:(NSString*)body bubblePoint:(CGPoint)rect hidesAfter:(float)delay show:(BOOL)show;

@end
```

**MOBubbleView.m:**

```
+ (MOBubbleView*)hudWithBody:(NSString*)body bubblePoint:(CGPoint)point hidesAfter:(float)delay show:(BOOL)show {

    MOBubbleView *bubble = [[MOBubbleView alloc] init];

///....

    if (show) [bubble addToWindow];

    return bubble;
}

- (void)addToWindow {
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:self.view];
}

- (void)loadView {
    CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

   /// .. my animation


}

- (void) dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Close myView");
}

@end
```

Comment: What retains the `MOBubbleView`?  Why don't you use the name `MOBubbleViewController` (given a "view" is not a "view controller")?

Comment: What is myView in "myView alloc"? It is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to retain the view controller that you are returning from your call, so do:

```
pMyViewController = [myView hudWithBody:@"123123" bubblePoint:CGPointMake(220, headerMenu.center.y) hidesAfter:2 show:YES];
```

where `pMyViewController` is declared somewhere that it won't go out of scope - say a global variable for now:

e.g. `myView* pMyViewController;`

You have added the view part of the view controller onto the window, so that's retained, but the actual controller part has no references holding on to it, so it gets deallocated.

Comment: Yes, when I declared global variable second controller on main controller, all work. But MOBubbleView *bubble = [[MOBubbleView alloc] init]; is retained when I called them. I saw many examples where used this method, but I can't understand how

Comment: I want to view my "bubble" in main view and when I tap anywhere deallocated self. But he is dealloc himself when start